# Jira - Zephyr Test case import is marked as "successful", but no test case is created

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-zephyr

I'm trying to import test cases into JIRA with the Zephyr Testcase importer: I followed the tutorial on Zephyr website,  and this is the message I get in the log:

> Mon Oct 26 16:23:58 CET 2015 file:///Users/Sam/Downloads/AOTCDM 10 -
>   Geotagging.xlsx normalization success..!  Mon Oct 26 16:23:58 CET 2015
>   AOTCDM 10 - Geotagging.xlsx imported successfully..!

But for some reason, no new testcase is created in Jira.

Anyone with the same issue ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been solved via [Zephyr's ticketing system](http://support.getzephyr.com). We reviewed the support case and it looks like the issue is resolved by mapping the external ID and Descriptions with the respective columns in the excel sheet.
Thank you.

Regards,

Zephyr Support